# Trigger insert into multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have got 2 tables named: **train_information** and **axle**.

```
Train_information
```

has the folowing:

```
train_id (PK)
train_name
train_length
number_of_axles
```

---

```
axle
```

has the folowing:

```
axle_id (PK)
train_id(FK)
axle
```

When I insert something on ***train_information*** and let's say for example put the number 16 in ***number_of_axles***. I want the table **axle** to get that same information automatically.

How do i do this with a trigger?

***EDIT:***

it works now with this code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName AFTER INSERT ON train_information
FOR EACH
ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO axle( train_id, axle ) 
VALUES (
NEW.train_id, NEW.number_of_axles
);

END
```

But right now, it enters for example the number 16 in the table **axle**
but i want it to go like:

```
axle_id = 1
train_id = 1
axle = 1

axle_id = 2
train_id = 1
axle = 2

axle_id = 3
train_id = 1
axle = 3
```

Is this posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `AFTER TRIGGER` on `Train_information` table, something like this:

**SQL**
*More about [After Triggers in SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)*

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
   ON Train_information
   FOR INSERT
   AS
   BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      INSERT INTO axle
        (train_id, axle)
    SELECT
        train_id, 'axle_name'
        FROM inserted
    END
```

---

**MySQL**
*More about [After Triggers in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html)*

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
   AFTER INSERT ON Train_information FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO axle (train_id, axle)
      VALUES (NEW.train_id, NEW.axle_name)            
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I get the following error: MySQL meldt: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON train_information FOR INSERT AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON ' at line 2       I'm using phpmyadmin

Comment: So are you using MySQL?

Comment: Yes, i click on: add trigger. There i have to fill in the name etc. and a field that says: Definition. There i fill the code in.

Comment: Updated my answer how It should be in `MySQL`, check It. Also added documentation to learn about triggers.

Comment: It still gives a syntax error, but i think i'm doing something wrong. I'l take a look at the documentation! thank you!

Comment: It works right now, but i edited something in the main question. Do you know if this is posible or not?